# Inserting data from a form into a table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

it's been probably 3 years since I have had to use VB or VBA code. I am working on a project for work where I need to take the information that is listed on the form and insert it into a table. What I am stuck on is the last part of the code the values part. This is what I have so far.

INSERT Volunteers (Name, Email, Number, Emergency Contact, Emergency Number) VALUES (and this is where I get stuck)

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: You have a lot of extraneous tags there.  If it is Access DB, it isnt MySQL, if it is VBA or Access-VBA it isnt VB.NET

Answer (score 0):

INSERT Volunteers (Name, Email, Number, Emergency Contact, Emergency Number) VALUES ('Name_Value','Email_Value','Number_Value','Emergency_Value','Number_Value')
is the syntax for more info here is more details [Link to SQL Insert](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)